# C# Unit Testing MVC Controller Action Parameter for Null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Is it worth testing an MVC Controller action parameter for `null` values? The purpose is to ensure valid values are passed to the action and I guess `null` is also a possibility.

Here is the controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ContactViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Create", viewModel);

        if (viewModel == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No data received");

        var contact = Mapper.Map<Contact>(viewModel);

        //contact.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        contact.UserId = _user.Id;

        _unitOfWork.Contacts.Add(contact);

        _unitOfWork.Complete();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And my test for checking the null parameter:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreatePost_NullViewModelPassed_ShouldReturnBadRequest()
    {
        var result = _controller.Create(null) as HttpStatusCodeResult;
        result.StatusCode.Should().Be(400);
    }
```

The above test always passes, but, is this a useful test? I have been trying to hit the post method with Postman but I get the `HttpGet` version of my `Create` action:

```
    public ViewResult Create()
    {
        return View("Create", new ContactViewModel());
    }
```

Comment: Show some more logic of the method under test

Comment: You may need to provide more code related to your problem. Try to provide an example that is self-contained, as small as possible and reproduces your problem. As far as your tests, you should try to cover as much as possible. If your class/method accept a null value (and particularly if that null value can mean a difference in execution) then you should test for it. Similarly, if you should not accept null values, your method should throw an `ArgumentNullException` (or similar), which you should test for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tests you're writing should give confidence of the system under test, but also raise bugs where possible to be resolved. If you have null checking in your `Create` method then it is a very valid test to ensure the system doesn't just "die" when it receives a null value, instead it should respond accordingly which it seems to be doing by retrieving a status code of 400 (Bad Request), so overall I'd say the test is very valid - particularly where you may refactor in the future to introduce something such as the repository/services pattern.

The tests for the `Create` method should cover all angles, not just successful and unsuccessful calls, but calls with various values in your view model, and just about any combination that could change the logic - such as booleans wrapped in conditionals to perform different tasks based on a certain value

Alas, if you want to hit the Post method in Postman then be sure to change the METHOD to `POST` just before the URL.

Comment: I actually tried it with the `POST` method with the example in my question

Comment: Do you have the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute applied to the method?

Comment: I had removed it before asking the question for simplifying it, however, adding it back on resulted in hitting the correct action. Thank you!